# lists of discriminated unions in fsharp

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

Can anybody explain why following 2 let statements don't work?

```
 type Rank =
 | Two
 | Three
 | Four
 | Five
 | Six
 | Seven
 | Eight
 | Nine
 | Ten

 type Face =
 | Jack
 | Queen
 | King
 | Ace

 type Suit =
 | Diamonds
 | Clubs
 | Hearts
 | Spades

 type Card =
 | RankCard of Rank * Suit
 | FaceCard of Face * Suit


 let deck : Card = [ (Two, Diamonds); (Jack, Hearts) ]
```

This expression was expected to have type Card but here has type 'a list

and this let gives

```
 let deck : Card list = [ (Two, Diamonds); (Jack, Hearts) ]
```

expression was expected to have type     Card     but here has type     'a * 'b

Answer (score 10):

F# is a type-safe language. So the first expression is wrong since `Card` and `'a list` are incompatible. The second expression is also incorrect because your annotation requires list elements in `Card` type but you provided tuples instead.

Moreover, `(Two, Diamonds)` and `(Jack, Hearts)` are not even legal to use in the same list. The former is a tuple of `Rank * Suit` and the latter is a tuple of `Face * Suit`.

Your intention is creating two values of type `Card`; you have to provide appropriate constructors based on different union cases of `Card`:

```
let c1 = RankCard (Two, Diamonds)  // c1: Card
let c2 = FaceCard (Jack, Hearts) // c2: Card
```

Now you can use `c1` and `c2` in the same list `deck`, and F# type checker will automatically infer `deck` to have the type of `Card list`:

```
let deck = [c1; c2] // deck: Card list
```

Alternatively, you have a list as follows:

```
let deck = [RankCard (Two, Diamonds); FaceCard (Jack, Hearts)]
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `RankCard` or `FaceCard` constructor -- otherwise F# thinks you've just given it a normal list of tuples.

Alternatively, why not let F# infer the types itself?

Comment: I usually try to let type inference work by itself first and only add type annotations if I need to.